# Code assistance for Node.js in PhpStorm 2016.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I installed PhpStorm 2016.2 with enabled plugin NodeJS, NodeJS v.6.3.0. When I trying enable code assistance pressing on the button "Enable" nothing happens. Consequently, IDE can not correctly highlight simple code in js file.
What I can do for enabling code highlight?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to *Languages & frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries* and see if you see *Node.js Core    predefined* enabled

Comment: But I don't have this library here. How correctly add this library?

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Enable" where it says "Node.js Core library is not enabled"?

Comment: Yes, many times. Nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that in your question. What is the error when you hover over `module`?

Comment: "Unresolved variable or type module"

Answer (score 3):

`Preferences` => `Languages & Frameworks` => `Node.js and NPM` => `Coding Assistance` => Enable `Node.js Core Library`.

Answer (score 1):

All fine after install new version IDE.

Comment: I installed version 2016.3.4 and it still didn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

just put you cursor where webstorm/phpstorm underlines you the line, then press **Alt+Enter** and "Enable coding assistance", It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.2/node-v6.2.2-x86.msi

JetBrains and Node.js are x32 in windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After checking my plugins, I found the NodeJS plugin was disabled.

After enabling and restarting I could toggle 'coding assistence for Node.js' again (PhpStorm 2019.2).